# iPad "copy" event handler

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, jquery-mobile, event-handling

Is there anyway we can attach a event handler to `copy` event in iPad/iPhone?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `oncopy` event which works in almost all the standard browser. Luckily it works on iPad too.

```
//Since there is no "copy" method exposed by jQuery I am using "on" method
$(document).on('copy', function(){
    //Copy event triggered
});
```

Similarly `cut` and `paste` events also work.

Note: Instead of `document` if you want to handle event only one a specific container even that works too.

```
$('containerSelector').on('copy', function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [spec (link)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) copy/paste events are not suppoerted in iOS

Answer (score 0):

arriving late here, but I see 2 ways:

- if listening to the copy event of an input, just add a `oncopy` property to the `<input>` (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oncopy.asp)
- if listening to the copy event on any DOM element (can be the whole `document`, but any other DOM element including `input`), add an event listener to "copy":

  ```
  document.addEventListener("copy", callback);
  ```